# wax about Orthodox swords but don't actually go to church much -- meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms, figurative-language

Usage example with [a context](http://www.businessinsider.com/why-putin-will-lose-2015-1):

> Ukraine's Orthodox Church, which is powerful politically — Ukrainians tend to be more personally devout than Russians, who like to wax about **Orthodox swords** but don't actually go to church much — has explained that it rejects Western post-modern values but emphatically does not reject Europe or democracy.

What do they mean by *Orthodox swords*? Something idiomatic, maybe?

Comment: It's an incorrect use of the verb **wax** anyway (OED: *intr. To speak or write (increasingly) **in the manner specified**; esp. in "to wax **lyrical**", "to wax **eloquent**"*), so I wouldn't take too much notice of this writer's obscure usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - is it wrong to omit "lyrical" or "eloquent", or is it wrong to use **about** with **wax**?

Comment: @CopperKettle: In this highly specific context, ***to wax*** is effectively "archaic", but the collocation with  "lyrical" (and to a lesser extent, "eloquent") is a "fixed expression". As OED says, it needs to be followed by an adjective/adverb describing ***how*** one is "waxing". I don't think *about [subject of discourse]* meets that criterion, especially given it's commonplace to use *wax lyrical **on/about** [some topic]*. OP's cited writer is just attempting to sound more erudite and linguistically competent than he actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ukraine's Orthodox Church, which is powerful politically — Ukrainians tend to be more personally devout than Russians, who like to wax about **Orthodox swords** but don't actually go to church much — has explained that it rejects Western post-modern values but emphatically does not reject Europe or democracy.

Idiomatic? I don't think so. Looks like an imaginative use of phrasing.

My imagination brings up images of "sword-bearing protectors of Orthodox christianity". Maybe the word **swords** stands for "people who (in the past) took up swords to protect their faith, their Orthodox country". For "warriors", to put it simply.

So in a way the adjective *Orthodox* describes warriors. Russians wax lyrical of the past exploits of their *Orthodox warriors*, but attend churches less than Ukrainians.

Some distance before your quote, the article mentions a think-tank head who

> ..has transformed into a militant religious believer with Big Ideas and enthusiastic backer of Putin’s **Orthodox Jihad**.

So the idea of the article is that Putin wages an Orthodox Jihad, relying on the imagery of "Orthodox swords (warriors)" to fuel the zeal of the "volunteers".

From Shakespeare:

> I will lay odds that, ere this year expire,
>   We bear our **civil swords** and native fire
>   As far as France: I heard a bird so sing,
>   Whose music, to my thinking, pleased the king.

The story is old and repetitive, just replace *France* with *Ukraine* and *civil* with *Orthodox*.